# selenide.open attempt throws NoSuchMethodError

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, selenide

I'm trying to simply navigate to google page:

```
String url = "https://www.google.com";
Selenide.open(url);
```

and the exact exception thrown is:

```
    java.util.stream.Collector com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.toImmutableList()'
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.stream.Collector com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.toImmutableList()'
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions.asMap(ChromeOptions.java:292)
    at org.openqa.selenium.MutableCapabilities.merge(MutableCapabilities.java:73)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.MergeableCapabilities.<init>(MergeableCapabilities.java:19)
    at ...
```

I use Chrome  86.0.4240.111 (64-bit) and selenide 5.15.1

Answer (score 0):

The point is that selenide is not compatible with test-ng, at least with this version mentioned in gradle

```
testCompile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '7.3.0'
compile group: 'com.codeborne', name: 'selenide', version: '5.15.1'
```

Removing test-ng solved the problem